# PagerAdapter instantiating class twice

Tags: java, c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have done a ton of reading on this issue but I am still at a loss on how to solve it. Basically, I have a view pager which then has a pager adapter class and that will instantiate my fragments using

```
    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Batches();
            case 1:
                return new Track();
            case 2:
                return new Post();
            case 3:
                return new Upload();
            case 4:
                return new Admin();
            default:
                return new Track();
        }


    }
```

I understand that this naming is misleading (based on another SO post I read) because this method actually creates the instance to the class OR returns it if already created (ie when you are swiping pages.

That said, I needed some custom lifecycle events to raise on my fragments when you do swipe pages. Based on other reading I did on SO, it was determined that creating a custom interface was the best way to go. So, this is what I did:

Interface

```
interface ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager
{
    void onPausePagerFragment();
    void onResumePagerFragment(int prevPage);
}
```

Activity calling based on view pager page changed event

```
    private void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        int position = (int)e.Position;

        ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager fragmentToResume = (ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager)adapter.InstantiateItem(viewPager, position); 
        fragmentToResume.onResumePagerFragment(previousActiveFragment);

        ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager fragmentToPause = (ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager)adapter.InstantiateItem(viewPager, previousActiveFragment);
        fragmentToPause.onPausePagerFragment();

        previousActiveFragment = position;
    }
```

Finally, an example of the implementation on one of the fragments

```
    public void onPausePagerFragment()
    {
        //deInitScanner();
    }
```

Now, here is where the issue lies. While the GetItem call above in my pager adapter class is supposed to only create the first instance otherwise return instances, I found that my interface will call GetItem and that it DOES create a second (unwanted) instance of a class.

When my application starts up, in the onResume lifecycle, I have a method call that determines which page to show on startup by default. That logic then calls another method to perform the page change. When it performs the page change, the ViewPager_PageSelected event is raised for my custom lifecycles. Because those use InstantiateItem (and maybe that is the issue) it will instantiate a new instance of the class. I have ensured that I do not set the page until After GetItem has run through and created instances to all my classes but it still creates a new one when it is called later.

I see this if I hit a break point, much later in my application, where I have an instance to the SupportFragmentManager and when I inspect that, I see two instances of my fragment(s).

I suspect the problem is either:
1. I need to use something different than InstantiateItem on my interface to force it to grab an instance to the already existing class?
2. The GetItem call sees InstantiateItem being called from something other than the view pager, thus has a different tag and therefore, GetItem thinks it has not created an instance of the class and creates another?

Either way, I am not sure how to fix it given this use case.

Please help!

EDIT - I have tried this solution to store the class if it is already instantiated and return that instead of creating new everytime. Basically in the pager adapter class, global to GetItem, I did something like this for each of the classes:

```
Batches batches;
Track track;
```

Then, in the GetItem method, I modified the case statements a bit to do this:

```
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                if (batches == null)
                {
                    batches = new Batches();
                }
                return batches;
            case 1:
                if (track == null)
                {
                    track = new Track();
                }
                return track;
```

I cut that off but I do it for all of the cases. However, I now get this exception.

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: Track{42350aa8 #1 id=0x7f070097 android:switcher:2131165335:1}

EDIT - Here is the screenshot of the stack trace. Not too much to show.
[image: Stack Trace of Exception]

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the stacktrace for the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Done. I added a screen shot showing it all instead. Thank you for the help!

Comment: For further information, if I comment out the two (fragmentToPause and fragmentToResume) interface calls in ViewPager_PageSelected, the exceptions go away, all starts up fine and I don't have more than one instance of each class in the SupportFragmentManager. So, as I eluded to before, they are definitely the cause of the issue. However, I sort of need them else where. Maybe a different approach can be taken though. The goal was to raise and event on the fragment that is left and the one that is scrolled to on a view page swipe.

Comment: Please copy and paste the full stacktrace. Images are difficult to view on many screen sizes. Also a screenshot may leave out critical info.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. I will be posting my answer to the question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clues, more reading and some testing, I believe I found the answer. However, please, if somebody objects or knows a better way...correct me.

When used with pager adapter, I have learned that InstantiateItem will create an instance of a class/fragment each time if using just the base implementation. It would be up to the developer to override this and store the created fragment once it is created and then return it using GetItem. I also know that InstantiateItem will call GetItem.

What I believe was happening was, my implementation of GetItem was simply creating an instance of the fragment. I was not explicitly storing the instance of them after they were created. That said, it was not completely necessary because if the SupportFragmentManager already has an instance of the class, it would not need to call GetItem and that is how multiple instances are not created each time.

That said, my custom lifecycle interface that I implemented (see OP above) was calling InstantiateItem. Therefore, when this would get called and used, it would create yet another instance of my fragments(s) because the instance that was already created before had a different Tag name. So, I would have two (but only two). One that was created by the pager adapter and one that was created by InstantiateItem which was called from my interface.

So, the fix is (and it seems to be working) is:

1. Change GetItem so that it will store a reference to the fragment after it is created and either return the stored instance or create new if null. Like this

   ```
    Batches batches;

    if (batches == null) {
        batches = new Batches();
    }
    return batches;
   ```
2. Ensure that the pager adapter class is complete and GetItem has created an instance to the classes (and stored them) BEFORE the interface can call. This ensures that the instance that is created and stored is the instance for the pager adapter and has the correct tag.
3. Finally, the biggest change. The implementation of the interface that I was using was calling InstantiateItem (I got this off of SO) to get a reference to the class. As mentioned above, this was instead creating a new instance. However, if I change it to GetItem, it will simply get and return the instance of the fragment that was created and stored by the pager adapter. So, it should look like this:

   ```
   ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager fragmentToResume = (ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager)adapter.GetItem(position);  //InstantiateItem(viewPager, position);
    fragmentToResume.onResumePagerFragment(previousActiveFragment);
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> this method actually creates the instance to the class OR returns it if already created

This method will only fulfill this requirement if you make tell it to do so. Currently you are creating a new instance of the requested class every time this method is called.

To fix this, you need to store the instances the first time you create them. Then you can return the same instance if it has already been created. It will take a little bit more code to do this.

Comment: I have edited my post above to show my implementation based on your suggestion. I am getting an exception so either I did not implement properly or there is something else going on.